# Jolt use value as key lookup

Tags: jolt

Giving the input:

```
{
  "influencers": [
    {
      "influencer_field_name": "COULD_BE_WHATEVER_STRING"
    }
  ],
  "COULD_BE_WHATEVER_STRING": [
    "abcdefg"
  ]
}
```

The output should be:

```
{
  "influencer_id": "abcdefg"
}
```

How do i use Jolt to pick up the value of the `influencer_field_name` and lookup a key with that value?

Is this even possible in Jolt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for future reference...

After some fiddling i found the solution. Not sure this is the best way to do it, but here it is.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(influencers[0].influencer_field_name)": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,&[0])": "influencer_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So basically we traverse to the path `influencers[0].influencer_field_name` and then we save the value with `*` so we can use it in `&`.

Then we go up a 2 levels and fetch the value of the key and extract the first element of the array `@(2,&[0])`.

That's it... Bye!